# Add Value to Core Image Filter using Swift

Tags: swift, core-image

I am using CIImage to add a number of different filter types to an image. All filters are working fine with their default values, plus the CIPixellate and CICrystallize filters are working with kCIInputScaleKey and kCIInputRadiusKey values added respectfully. Howsever I am having trouble adding values for the CILineOverlay filter. I would like to feed it a specific value for inputEdgeIntensity. The Core Image Filter Reference docs state:

inputEdgeIntensity:
An NSNumber object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypeScalar and whose display name is Edge Intensity.

Default value: 1.00

But I can't find an example anywhere of how to add this value using swift. Using this code does not work:

```
filter?.setValue(CGFloat(intensity), forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
```

Can anybody please help me with the correct format/syntax for specifying an inputEdgeIntensity scalar value for CILineOverlay using Swift?

Thanks

```
enum ImageEffects: String {
    case bloom = "CIBloom"
    case chrome = "CIPhotoEffectChrome"
    case comic = "CIComicEffect"
    case crystallize = "CICrystallize"
    case fade = "CIPhotoEffectFade"
    case instant = "CIPhotoEffectInstant"
    case invert = "CIColorInvert"
    case lineOverlay = "CILineOverlay"
    case mono = "CIPhotoEffectMono"
    case noir = "CIPhotoEffectNoir"
    case none = "None"
    case pixellate = "CIPixellate"
    case poster = "CIColorPosterize"
    case process = "CIPhotoEffectProcess"
    case sepia = "CISepiaTone"
    case spotColor = "CISpotColor"
    case tonal = "CIPhotoEffectTonal"
    case transfer = "CIPhotoEffectTransfer"
}

let imageEffectsArtistic: [(ImageEffects, String, Float, Bool, Float, Float)] = [
    // Effect type, effect display name,
    // default intensity setting, show slider?,
    // min slider value, max slider value
    (.none, "None", 0, false, 0, 0),
    (.comic, "Comic", 0, false, 0, 0),
    (.crystallize, "Crystallize", 30, true, 10, 100),
    (.lineOverlay, "Line", 0, false, 0, 0),
    (.pixellate, "Pixellate", 30, true, 10, 100),
    (.poster, "Poster", 0, false, 0, 0),
    (.spotColor, "Spot Color", 0, false, 0, 0)
]


if var outputImage = CIImage(image: image) {
    let extent = outputImage.extent
    let filterList = effect.rawValue.split(separator: ",")
        
    for filterItem in filterList {
        let filter = CIFilter(name: String(filterItem))
        filter?.setDefaults()
        filter?.setValue(outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        
        switch effect {
        case .crystallize:
            filter?.setValue(CGFloat(intensity), forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        case .pixellate:
            filter?.setValue(CGFloat(intensity), forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
        default:
            ()
        }

        if let newOutputImage = filter?.outputImage {
            outputImage = newOutputImage
        }
    }
    
    let outputCGImage = self.context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: extent)!
    imageToReturn = UIImage(cgImage: outputCGImage)
} else {
    imageToReturn = image
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant `kCIInputIntensityKey` maps to `"inputIntensity"`, but you want to set `"inputEdgeIntensity"`. You should be able to do this like that:

```
filter?.setValue(CGFloat(intensity), forKey: "inputEdgeIntensity")
```

(Not every filter parameter name has a corresponding `kCIInput...` constant.)

Comment: Thanks Frank and please Ignore my earlier comment, now deleted. I was incorrectly trying to apply your fix to the wrong filter. Thanks for your help.